# Identifier must be declared? PLS-00201

Tags: sql, plsql

```
declare
    v_title movie.title%type;
    v_release movie.release_date%type;
begin
    for i in 121..500 loop
        select a.title, a.release_date into v_title, v_release
        from movie a
        where a.running_time=i;

        if a.genre_id=015 then
            dbms_output.put_line(v_title|| ' '||v_release);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Can you tell me why it doesn't recognize genre_id while it recognizes title or release_date? I checked my table and there is no typo error. The genre_id exists in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.genre_id` is a column in the table. When you are using that in `IF`, then for PLSQL, it is not a valid variable/

Assuming rest of the code is correct, add another variable

```
declare
    v_title movie.title%type;
    v_release movie.release_date%type;
    v_genre_id movie.genre_id%type;
begin
    for i in 121..500 loop
        select a.title, a.release_date , a.genre_id into v_title, v_release , v_genre_id 
        from movie a
        where a.running_time=i;

        if v_genre_id=015 then
            dbms_output.put_line(v_title|| ' '||v_release);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a variable `v_genre_id` and add it to your select, but there is a much faster way. Your code would execute the same query 380 times, when it should only be executed once:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT a.title, a.release_date
      FROM movie a
     WHERE a.running_time BETWEEN 121 AND 500
       AND a.genre_id = 15
     ORDER BY a.running_time
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( cur.title || ' ' || cur.release_date);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a table alias, defined for the query:

```
    select a.title, a.release_date into v_title, v_release
    from movie a
    where a.running_time = i;
```

It is not defined outside this query.  Hence, `a.genre_id` is not understood.  If you want to capture the genre as well, you need to capture it in a variable.